# Bash: test whether original script was run with `-x`

Tags: bash

Is it possible to test whether a bash script was executed with `-x`?

I'm writing a script which also runs some remote scripts, and I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
USE_X="$( run_with_x && "-x" || "" )"
ssh $host "bash $USE_X some_script.sh"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just look at the `$-` variable.

```
USE_X=`case "$-" in *x*) echo "-x" ;; esac`
```

(Yup, I did manage to do that without invoking grep.  Save the pids!)

Comment: what does `*x*` expand to?

Comment: What a waste of pid! `case $- in *x*) USE_X="-x";; *) USE_X=;; esac` @bbaja42 It doesn't expand to anything: it's a pattern that the string `$-` is matched against.

Comment: @Gilles Your example also contains unnecessary part: `*) USE_X=;;` changes nothing, if `USE_X` was not set previously. Also, the whole `case` construct is unnecessary ([see my version](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21922/bash-test-whether-original-script-was-run-with-x/21944#21944) - isn't that simpler?)

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz This part is unnecessary if `USE_X` has been initialized earlier on. I don't consider your version simpler: it's a few characters shorter (and even then only if `USE_X` has been initialized, otherwise it's longer), but at the expense of clarity and portability.

Comment: @Gilles *Portability* is not the subject of this question, it is about bash. *Initializing* `USE_X` is not necessary for the purpose of OP's intended use (to pass `$USE_X` to further scripts). *Using `case` construct* looks less clear and natural than a regular condition evaluation in my view.

Answer (score 9):

This expression will be true if the script is run with `-x`, false otherwise: `[[ $- =~ x ]]`
So this expression will be "-x" if  the script is run with `-x` and "" (empty) otherwise: `$([[ $- =~ x ]] && echo "-x")`

Comment: It's a stretch to say "readable" and "bash" in the same sentence, but since any non-casual bash user MUST get familiar with the bash regex syntax, your (currently lowest-voted) answer wins for readability in my book (and, of course, doesn't require starting any processes or anything astoundingly inefficient).

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: This expression removes all non-x characters from $-, so it is empty if there is no x: `${-//[^x]}`
If you assign this to variable, like: `x=${-//[^x]}` then the following expression will be empty when there was no x and -x otherwise: `${x:+-x}`  Combine like: `x=${-//[^x]} USE_X=${x:+-x}`  Or if you don't want to use an extra variable, you can reuse USE_X:  `USE_X=${-//[^x]} USE_X=${USE_X:+-x}`  This is much much faster than doing a regular expression comparison! (But less readable just looking at the code, figuring out what it does...)

Answer (score 7):

Probably the simplest way of parsing `$-`, similar to [dagbrown's method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21922/9382) (also pure `bash`), but without using `case` and backticks (subshell):

```
if  [[ ${-/x} != $- ]] ; then USE_X="-x"; fi
```

or even shorter:

```
[[ ${-/x} != $- ]] && USE_X="-x"
```

Note that `[[` is *not* an invocation of `test` builtin program (as is the case with `[`), but a bash syntax construct (according to `man bash` and [this dev recommendation](http://devmanual.gentoo.org/tools-reference/bash/index.html)). So I claim it to be "purer bash" ;)

Comment: Nice solution. I suggest tagging '|| USE_X="+x"' on the end of the second expression so you may then call 'set "$USE_X"' and it will work to restore the initial setting whether or not xtrace was set.

Answer (score 4):

The bash man page documents `set -o xtrace` as equivalent to `set -x`, which in turn is equivalent to giving `-x` as an argument to the shell.  (So far, this is compatible with SUSv3 sh, with the caveat that `-o option` is required "if the system supports the User Portability Utilities option".)

Also, `set -o` without an option prints the current status of all of the `-o` options.  (SUSv3 specifies this as well, but not usefully; the format is unspecified, so you can only depend on it if you know you're running a shell that uses a format similar to bash's.)

So, the pipeline `set -o | grep xtrace | grep -q on` should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

After reading man pages and grepping for things, here's the solution:

```
$ cat show_x.sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(set | grep xtrace)" ]; then
    echo "xtrace is on. :D"
else
    echo "xtrace is off. :("
fi
```

Result:

```
$ bash show_x.sh 
xtrace is off. :(

$ bash -x show_x.sh 
++ set
++ grep xtrace
+ '[' SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments:xtrace ']'
+ echo 'xtrace is on. :D'
xtrace is on. :D
```

Comment: "set" will show you all the functions and env vars to, and if any of those contain "xtrace" the solution will fail.